# ANOVA is not significant but coefficient variables are significant?

Tags: statistics, regression, anova

I have produced an ANOVA from a generalised least squares model (longevity ~ mating system) and it was non significant (0.08). However, when I run the model with summary(), I can see each coefficient (types of mating systems) is significant.

From what I've read (multiple times), the ANOVA shows if variance in the independent variable can be significantly explained by the dependent variable. Whilst a regression model will test how the dependent variable changes with a change in the levels of an independent variable.

However, I feel like I'm missing something as I'm not sure I fully understand what the p-values of single levels of a dependent variable mean, and also what the overall p-value of a dependent variable in ANOVA test means.

I'm hoping someone could explain my results in fairly layman terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say you put people under different levels of load (`low`, `medium`, `high`), which we will call your independent variable (same as mating system in your case) and you measure their reaction time (`rt`) to something, which will be the dependent variable (longevity in your case)

So in R, your model would look something like `rt ~ load`

**ANOVA**

When you run a one-way ANOVA, the question youre testing is *"are the mean RT values in the low, medium, and high groups the same as each other?"*

More formally, in hypothesis testing, you have whats called a null hypothesis. In the ANOVA case, the null hypothesis is: `mean(low) = mean(medium) = mean(high)`, which is another way of saying that the group means are all equal

The ANOVA tests whether that null hypothesis can be rejected, which is what your p value is telling you. In your case, `p = .08`, you retain the null. You would conclude that the means of all the groups are in fact equal

**Regression**

Regression operates slightly differently, and its this difference that is causing differences in your results.

When you have a categorical variable in regression, dummy variables are created by R. This happens by first choosing a reference level (lets say `low` is the reference). 2 dummy variables are then created, which contrasts each of your other levels against your reference. So your 2 dummy variables are comparing **low vs. medium** and **low vs. high**

You'll notice in the summary of regression models that you have multiple coefficients and multiple p values. **These coefficients are for each of your dummy variables**

You mentioned in your original post the idea of levels: "regression model will test how the dependent variable changes with a change in the levels". This is where that idea comes into play

Lets take one of the dummy variables, for example, the one for low vs. high. That dummy has a corresponding coefficient and p value. What do they mean?

The coefficient is telling you what change in `rt` you should expect if you go from the `low` group to the `high` group. `low`, `medium` and `high` are also what are called "levels" of your load factor. So the "change in levels" is referring to going from low to high - what is the corresponding change in the dependent variable (`rt`) if that were to happen?

More generally you can think of this as testing whether the mean of the low group is the same as the mean of the high group

The p value is then telling you whether that change (or mean difference) is significantly different from 0 (i.e. is there a meaningful amount of change in RT between low and high? or do the low and high groups have the same mean RT?)

So in summary, you can see that ANOVA and regression are testing slightly different things. Regression is more targeted and tests for a difference between specific levels, whereas the omnibus ANOVA is more broad and testing all levels of the factor for equality

Comment: Thank you so much @Simon, you've given a fantastic answer and made it very clear for me to understand what exactly happens with ANOVA and regression. I hope people who find themselves asking the same q as me find your post.